# How to save chats to database context c#

Tags: c#, razor, signalr, blazor-server-side, signalr-hub

I'm trying to save chats on the database but I think I'm missing some part.

The context is inizialized:

```
public DbSet<ChatDB>? Chats { get; set; }
```

This is the class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChatDB
{
    [Key]
    public string? ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string? Username { get; set; }
    public List<MessagesDB> MessagesList { get; set; }

}

[Keyless]
[NotMapped]
public class MessagesDB
{
    public string? Body { get; set; }
    public bool Mine { get; set; }
    public string CSS => Mine ? "sent" : "received";
}
```

Here I'm adding messages to the database when the server receives them:

```
var FindUser = _context.Chats!.AsEnumerable();
foreach(var chat in FindUser)
{
     if(chat.Username == sender)
     {
        var messageslist = new MessagesDB(message, false);
        chat.MessagesList.Add(messageslist); //Here it gives me error - returned null.
        _context.Entry(chat).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

when I go through all the chats by username:

```
var FindUser = _context.Chats.AsEnumerable();
foreach (var chat in FindUser)
{
      if (chat.Username == PassUserNameClicked)
      {
           foreach(var messages in chat.MessagesList)
           {
                <div class="@messages.CSS">
                <div class="user">@chat.Username</div>
                <div class="msg">@messages.Body</div>
                </div>
            }
       }
 }
```

when I build the migration it gives me all empty:

```
public partial class AddChatsToDb : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Do you guys no what is going on? I believe the "list" inside the class broke the migration.

Comment: Looks like `MessagesList` is NULL. You need to include this property while retrieving chart list from the db. `var FindUser = _context.Chats.Include(c => c.MessagesList).AsEnumerable();`

Comment: MessagesDB has an empty constructor, try with `new MessgesDB(){Body = message, Mine = false}`

Comment: @Chetan Yes you are right you have to include MessagesList

Comment: But does anyone know why the migration is empty?

Comment: How many migration files do you have?

Comment: I have 5 Migrations files.

00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema, 
MyFiles,
MyDocuments,
Chats,
ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot

Comment: The configuration of the Chats table is in one of the files, when adding a migration and there is no modification in the DbContext files, an empty migration file is generated.

Comment: That make sense. By the way, I just tried to add the "Chetan" suggestion, it works but then it gives me and error null in the blazor page, when I'm loooping thought the list. Do you guys think that the "list" itself is not written correctly in the class?

Comment: In the blazor page, add a condition that wraps the loop

Comment: I did, I already tried. I added a breakpoint when I add the message to the DB and the message is null, like if there is no connection between Chats and Message. I strongly believe that the class is typed wrong, but I've no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs I figured it out, this is the class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChatDB
{
    [Key]
    public string? ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string? Username { get; set; }
    public MessagesDB? MessagesDBs { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MessagesDB
{
    [Key]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? WhoIs { get; set; }
    public string? Body { get; set; }
    public bool Mine { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string? ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string CSS => Mine ? "sent" : "received";
}
```

Just compile it, c# will connect the two classes via "ConnectionId".